# Racket Terminal: Command for exiting a current program?

Tags: racket

When running Racket in a command line, you can start running a racket program using

```
(enter! "yourfile.rkt")
```

How do we exit the  current .rkt program while still keeping Racket open in the command line?
Using

```
(exit)
```

closes Racket altogether instead of the current .rkt program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you could try it and the current namespace will restore to the original.

```
(enter! #f)
```